# Build a JSON_Object value in Flink SQL

Tags: sql, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a Flink Table for which I want to write a select query that will return a JSON Object based on some fields.

Here is the query I want to do (based on calcite syntax : https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#constructor-functions):

```
SELECT 
    myIdField,
    aFloatField,
    JSON_OBJECT('aFieldName':aFloatField)
FROM myTable
```

But when I try to use this query with Flink, I get the following error :

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: SQL validation failed. No match found for function signature JSON_OBJECT(<null>, , )
```

What is the good way to do so ? I can't find anything about this in Flink documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure Flink SQL supports using JSON in that way, but there is support for reading and writing JSON. What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: The result of my query is sent to a golang service that expect a JSON. (but not a json string). Maybe just converting the JSON string into a byte array might work, is it possible to do that in Flink SQL

Comment: Flink SQL supports user-defined functions (UDFs can be written in Java, Scala, or Python). You could wrap your call to the golang service in a UDF, or perhaps it would work to write a UDF that returns a byte array or json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON_OBJECT is supported in Flink 1.15:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/#json-functions